# How to create closure calling closure with less parameters in swift

Tags: swift, closures

I'm trying to create class in swift, that can take closure with 0..N arguments and then when callback function with N arguments will be invoked, will pass only required amount to closure.
I'm trying to do it like that:

```
class CallbackImpl: AuthServiceLogoutCallback {
    private let callback: ((UUID, AuthServiceLogoutType) -> Void )?
    
    public init( cb: @escaping ((UUID, AuthServiceLogoutType) -> Void ))
    {
        callback = { cb( $0, $1 ) }
    }
    
    public init( cb: @escaping ((UUID) -> Void ))
    {
        callback = { cb( $0 ) }
    }
    
    public init( cb: @escaping (() -> Void ))
    {
        callback = { cb() }
    }
    
    public func onEvent(_ userId: UUID, type: AuthServiceLogoutType)
    {
        callback!( userId, type )
    }
}
```

First init with closure with two arguments is ok, inits with closures with 1 and 0 arguments give me error **expression type '()' is ambiguous without more context**

What is the right way to do such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you are trying, if you give more context as to which closure parameter you are using and which not:

```
class CallbackImpl: AuthServiceLogoutCallback {
    private let callback: ((UUID, AuthServiceLogoutType) -> Void)?
    
    public init(cb: @escaping ((UUID, AuthServiceLogoutType) -> Void)) {
        callback = { cb($0, $1) }
    }
    
    public init(cb: @escaping ((UUID) -> Void)) {
        callback = { uuid, _ in cb(uuid) }
    }
    
    public init(cb: @escaping (() -> Void)) {
        callback = { _, _ in cb() }
    }
    
    public func onEvent(_ userId: UUID, type: AuthServiceLogoutType) {
        callback!( userId, type )
    }
}
```